# static final CharSequence to R.string.xxx how to do it properly?

Tags: java, android, charsequence

I wanna change hardcoded TITLE to resource from strings.xml

How to do it properly?

```
    public static final CharSequence TITLE = "Home";
```

```
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return HomeFragment.TITLE;

            case 1:
                return HistoryFragment.TITLE;

            case 2:
                return StatisticsFragment.TITLE;
        }
        return super.getPageTitle(position);
    }
}
```

```
    public static final CharSequence TITLE = R.string.title_home;
```

Comment: R.string.title_home will return integer value. Initialize the TITLE variable under the onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare `PUBLIC STATIC FINAL String` variable, because strings stored in resource file is unchangeable and can be accessed from anywhere at runtime.

**Use the following code**

```
@Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return context.getResources().getString(R.string.title_home);

            case 1:
                return context.getResources().getString(R.string.title_history);

            case 2:
                return context.getResources().getString(R.string.title_statistics);;
        }
        return super.getPageTitle(position);
    }
```